# Fitnesse: Slim server fails to start; using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm trying to get a very basic Fitnesse test to run; using Fitnesse / Slim; Java in Eclipse.

Test runs, or at least starts, but doesn't finish; get this error:

> Unable to start test system 'slim': fitnesse.slim.SlimError: Error SLiM server died before a connection could be established. JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

Fitnesse test is:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path: C:\Users\<my folder>\EclipseWorkspace\CalculatorProject
| import | packageCalculator |
| TestCalculator |
| operand | result? |
| 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 14 |
| 2 | 4 |
```

This is a similar issue: [Fitnesse: SLiM server died before a connection could be established](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942116/fitnesse-slim-server-died-before-a-connection-could-be-established); suggests this might be a regression bug; but I tried earlier versions of fitnesse, which made no difference

And it's not this one either: https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/726; there is no space in the classpath

Help!!!

Comment: Can you format the test in your question? It is hard to read like this.  I notice a sequence of two backslashes in your path. Is that correct? How are you starting your test, from the wiki? Which Java and fitnesse version do you use?

Comment: 1. Test pasted in as is; don't seem to be able to alter format - it looks fine to me??? 2. I can't see double backslashes??? 3. Yes, starting from wiki 4. Java is version 8, update 121 5. Fitnesse is latest version from http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesseDownload 6. Tried on IE & Opera - both fail 7. Windows 7 Professional